# Where do spatial indexes look for SRIDs?

Tags: coordinate-system, spatial-index, sql-server-spatial

I'm looking into optimizing the spatial indexes on some of our tables (stored in SQL Server 2008 R2), so I ran

```sql
exec sp_help_spatial_geometry_index 
    @tabname='myTable',
    @indexname='IX_myTable_Shape',
    @verboseoutput=1,
    @query_sample=@geomString
```

and that returned (among other stuff) `Number_Of_SRIDs_Found:  2`.  Troubled by that, I immediately did a `select count(*) from myTable where Shape.STSrid <> @mySrid` and saw 0.  Everything in the table is apparently using the correct SRID, so **where could sp_help_spatial_geometry_index be finding another SRID?**

I ran other spatial indexes through the same sproc and found 2 SRIDs for them as well.  Getting paranoid, I threw this together to look through all spatial columns in the entire database...

```sql
declare @tablename varchar(50)
declare @fieldname varchar(10)

DECLARE cSpatialColumns CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FOR
    SELECT  table_name [Table Name], column_name  [Column Name]
    FROM information_schema.columns c 
    where data_type = 'geometry' and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'vw%'

OPEN cSpatialColumns

FETCH FROM cSpatialColumns INTO @tablename, @fieldname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    declare @myquery nvarchar(1000)
    set @myquery = 'select count(*) as ' + @tablename + 'Count from ' + @tablename + ' where ' + @fieldname + '.STSrid <> 102605'
    exec sp_executesql @myquery
    FETCH FROM cSpatialColumns INTO @tablename, @fieldname
END
```

... and found no spatial objects at all that don't use our SRID of choice.  So I'm at a loss.  Could it be a matter of this being a bug in 2008 R2?

I tried looking at the SQL for that sproc but it simply executes another sproc to which I apparently don't have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<facepalm>

I didn't specify the SRID in my input geometry.  This change yielded but one SRID in the sproc's results.

```sql
declare @geom geometry
set @geom = geometry::STGeomFromText(@geomString,@mySrid)


exec sp_help_spatial_geometry_index 
    @tabname='locPLSTRS', 
    @indexname='IX_locPLSTRS_Shape',  
    @verboseoutput=1, 
    @query_sample=@geom
```

Comment: In my defense, why did the procedure accept my WKT without yelling!?!?

Comment: It happens to us all.  Chalk it up to `I won't do that again`